# Use SMTP Server in Windows 2012 from C#

Tags: c#, smtp, windows-server-2012

I need a SMTP server for Windows Server 2012 so that I will be able to intercept incoming emails from my C# application and display it to my clients via an ASP.NET application. Sorry if this would look like a trivial question but i cant figure out where should i start from.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious Windows SMTP server is Exchange, although there are plenty of free ones ([XMailServer](http://www.xmailserver.org/), [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/mailenable-mail-server.asp) or the lighter-weight [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/), which might serve your purpose) - I've not used anything other than Exchange, but a Google search will find you a tonne of them.

Is this just for sending messages from client to server, though? Unless there's some reason you need to have these messages as emails, it seems unlikely the overhead of setting up an entire email system, sending an email and then extracting the message and putting it into a web page is the best solution to your problem - have you considered a lighter-weight client-server messaging system, such as [DotNetMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193611/DotNetMQ-A-Complete-Message-Queue-System-for-NET) or simply sending your own messages directly through TCP sockets?